# delete stop words in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I Have a dataframe which has this structure:

```
Note.Reco Review Review.clean.lower
10 Good Products  good products
9 Nice film      nice film
....         ....
```

The first column is the rank of the film, then the second column is the customer's review then the 3rd column is the review with lowercase letters.

I try now to delete stop words with this:

```
Data_clean$Raison.Reco.clean1 <- Corpus(VectorSource(Data_clean$Review.clean.lower))
Data_clean$Review.clean.lower1 <- tm_map(Data_clean$Review.clean.lower1, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
```

But R studio crashes

Can you help me to resolve this problem please?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

```
#clean up
# remove grammar/punctuation
Data_clean$Review.clean.lower <- tolower(gsub('[[:punct:]0-9]', ' ', Data_clean$Review))

Data_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(Data_clean$Review.clean.lower))

Data_clean <- tm_map(Data_corpus,  removeWords, stopwords("french"))

train <- Data_clean[train.index, ]
test <- Data_clean[test.index, ]
```

So I get error when I run the 2 last instructions.

Comment: To subset a corpus use `Data_clean[train.index]`. A corpus is basically a list so use list subsetting not matrix/dataframe subsetting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below . You can do cleaning on the corpus and not column directly.

```
Data_corpus <-
  Corpus(VectorSource(Data_clean$Review.clean.lower))

  Data_clean <- tm_map(Data_corpus,  removeWords, stopwords("english"))
```

EDIT:
As mentioned by you, you want to be able to access the output after removing stop words, try the below instead of the above:

```
library(tm)

stopWords <- stopwords("en")

Data_clean$Review.clean.lower<- as.character(Data_clean$Review.clean.lower)
 '%nin%' <- Negate('%in%')
 Data_clean$Review.clean.lower1<-lapply(Data_clean$Review.clean.lower, function(x) {
  chk <- unlist(strsplit(x," "))
  p <- chk[chk %nin% stopWords]
  paste(p,collapse = " ")
})
```

Sample Output of above code:

```
>  print(Data_clean)
>       note Note.Reco.Review Review.clean.lower Review.clean.lower1
>     1   10    Good Products      good products       good products
>     2    9        Nice film     is a nice film           nice film
```

Also check the below:
[R remove stopwords from a character vector using %in%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253798/r-remove-stopwords-from-a-character-vector-using-in)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, In this case, how can I access to `Review.clean.lower`?  It seems impossible with `Data_clean`.

Comment: Could you please share a sample dataset and your end objective.