# How to consider "Long Stopword List" from http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords?

Tags: r, text, tm

I'm interested to remove all stopwords from my text using `R`. The list of stopwords that I want to remove can be found at http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords under the section which says "**Long Stopword List**" (a very long list version). I'm using `tm` package. Can one help me, please? Tnx!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delete stop words in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133509/delete-stop-words-in-r)

Comment: Please also take a look at the R documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qdap/versions/0.2.5/topics/stopwords .

Comment: The default English stopwords can be easily removed using `tm_map(text, removeWords, stopwords("en"))`. My problem is to consider all list of stopwords from the specified link.

Comment: Is your question on how to retrieve the lists of stop words or how to use `tm_map(text, removeWords, "any vector goes here" )`?

Comment: Sure! My question is how to directly access those lists. Is that possible?

Comment: Not really. I wanna to consider the most exhaustive list, however.

Comment: I already decided and indicated. Have you checked the link? In my case, words listed under the "Long Stopword List" are my focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy that list (after you select it in your browser) aand then paste it into this expression in R:

```
LONGSWS <- " <paste into this position> "
```

You would place the cursor for your editor or the IDE console device inside the two quotes. Then do this:

```
sw.vec <- scan(text=LONGSWS, what="")
#Read 474 items
```

The scan function needs to have the type of input specified via an example given to the `what` argument, and for that purpose just using `""` is sufficient for character types. Then you should be able to apply the code you offered in your comment:

```
 tm_map(text, removeWords, sw.vec)
```

You have not supplied an example `text` object. Using just a character vector is not successful:

```
 tm_map("test of my text", removeWords, sw.vec )
#Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
#  no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "character"
```

So we will need to assume you have a suitable object of a suitable class to place in the first position of the arguments to `tm_map`.  So using the example from the `?tm_map` help page:

```
> res <- tm_map(crude, removeWords, sw.vec )
> str(res)
List of 20
 $ 127:List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "Diamond Shamrock Corp said \neffective today   cut  contract prices  crude oil \n1.50 dlrs  barrel.\n    The re"| __truncated__
  ..$ meta   :List of 15
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "1987-02-26 17:00:56"
  .. ..$ description  : chr ""
  .. ..$ heading      : chr "DIAMOND SHAMROCK (DIA) CUTS CRUDE PRICES"
  .. ..$ id           : chr "127"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr "Reuters-21578 XML"
  .. ..$ topics       : chr "YES"
  .. ..$ lewissplit   : chr "TRAIN"
  .. ..$ cgisplit     : chr "TRAINING-SET"
   # ----------------snipped remainder of long output.
```